# Reference cells with no gaps to fill table with gaps

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have included 2 tables below to illustrate my problem.

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

I am trying to find a formula that fills rows 140, 143 & 146 (Table 2) from rows 15,16 & 17 (Table 1). There is over 100 so it is quite time consuming to input `=B15` etc over and over again.

The offset method e.g. `=OFFSET($B$15,(ROW()-1)*3,0)` only works when I'm referencing gaps, not trying to fill them.

Essentially, where B140's formula is `=B15`, B143's will be `=B140 + 1 row` i.e. B16

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying find value for appropriate month you can use `INDEX`/`MATCH` entered as array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(TRUE,MONTH(A10)=MONTH($A$1:$A$4),0)),"")
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

**Edit**

To find by month & year use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(1,(MONTH(A10)=MONTH($A$1:$A$4))*(YEAR(A10)=YEAR($A$1:$A$4)),0)),"")
```

it's also array formula

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo for this. With the Modulo function, you check if the remainder of the row you're on is divisible by a number (e.g. 3 if you want to copy a value every third row). `IF(MOD(ROW(E1);3 = 0)`

If that's the case, you can divide by 3 and use for example the Index function to copy the `nth` value of another location (or another worksheet). If that's not the case, you print `""` to get an empty row.

`=IF(MOD(ROW(E1);3)=0;INDEX($B$1:$B$4;ROW(E1)/3);"")`

[image]

If you're working with offsets because the row numbers are not on numbers divisible by three, you could manually offset the rows (and do the same for the division that yields the index row). For example, if you want to have rows 2, 5, 8 etc:

`=IF(MOD(ROW(E1)+1;3)=0;INDEX($B$1:$B$4;ROW(E2)+1/3);"")`

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. One other query I have. I realized every 12 cells there is a gap of one, to show the gap between the year. It's used to copy and paste into software. So the code only works every 12 rows, then a manual input is required. Is there a work around for this?